# Where is the SItecore command "ide:startwizard" located?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Sitecore has the concept of `commands` which are defined in commands.config and point to a class with `Execute()` method.

In the *core* database under the following item:

> /sitecore/content/Applications/Layouts/IDE/New File/Renderings/Sublayout

the command `ide:startwizard` is invoked. **Where is the commands.config entry for this command and where is the class that is used for this command?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no customizable class for this. This command is not in the `Commands.config` file. Based on what I see in the core database at the item you specified, this is such a built-in integral part of the internal Sitecore framework, this class is likely in one of the Sitecore DLLs, Kernel or Client.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is using Sitecore.Web.UI.HandleMessage attribute.  Take a look in Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Layouts.IDE.IDEForm if you want to see what the method is doing.